# How to use RxJava+Retrofit better?

Tags: java, android

I know that RxJava are created to make the code like a stream.However,in my codes,actually I have to make HTTP requests frequently,and I find it less elegant every time I use RxJava+Retrofit to do network job cause I have to write the same codes many times.
So I  enclosure the codes like below

```
public APIHelper(String url){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(setheader())
            .build();
}

private static OkHttpClient setheader() {

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request()
                            .newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("UserID", "")
                            .addHeader("hec-username", USERNAME)
                            .addHeader(AUTHENTICATION_KEY, TOKEN)
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }).build();
    return  httpClient;
}

public Retrofit getRetrofit(){
    if(retrofit!=null)
        return retrofit;
    else
        return null;
}

public void excuteRxJava(Observable<T> observable){
                observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(T t) {
                        doNext(t);
                    }
                });
}

public abstract void doNext(T t);

public abstract List<S> doInFrom(T t);

public abstract void doAction(T t);
```

Some other abstract methods are used to do something in onDoNext,flatMap e.g. And what I wanna ask is that,is this encapsulation suitable for the concept of Rx?

Answer (score -1):

make some utils class.

```
public class RetrofitUtils {
public static final String Tag = RetrofitUtils.class.getSimpleName();
public static <T> T getInstance(final Class<T> service)
{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constant.SERVER_URL)//做成静态变量
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    T t = retrofit.create(service);
    return t;
}
```

}

```
                final UserInterface instance = RetrofitUtils.getInstance(UserInterface.class);
                Observable<JsonElement> register = instance.resetPassword(Des3.encodeAndUrl(etUsername.getText().toString().trim()), Des3.encodeAndUrl(etPassword.getText().toString().trim()), etVcode.getText().toString().trim());
                RetrofitFlow.getData(register).subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(JsonElement jsonElement) {
                        LogUtil.i(jsonElement.toString());
                        RxBus.getDefault().post(new LoginJumpBean(null, LoginJumpBean.AIM_FINISH_ACTIVITY));
                    }
                });

public abstract class DefaultSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
    public static final String Tag = DefaultSubscriber.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        LogUtil.i("完成");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        LogUtil.i("发生错误:"+e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

use rxjava filter result。